# How can run filter: gray; filter: grayscale(100%) css in all browser

Tags: html

```
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%); -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
    filter: gray; filter: grayscale(100%);
```

How can run filter: gray; filter: grayscale(100%)  css  in all browser

Answer (score 0):

cross browser css polyfill https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill extra dumb characters for stacks filters